# How can i align the text in my python turtle code to be in the middle instead of being at the top?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Score: 0 High Score: 0", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
pen.write("Press Any Key To Start", move=False, align="center", font=("Courier", 40, "bold"))
```

i am trying to move the instructions to the middle of the screen. I have used align "center" but that move it to the top

Comment: Instead of posting a picture you should only provide code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell the turtle `goto(0,0)` in your case which is the center of your screen. `align=center` only means that it's centered at 0,0 like in MS-Word or sth. like that. Try `align=left` or `align=right`

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(1)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Score: 0 High Score: 0", move=True, align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
pen.goto(0,0)
pen.write("Press Any Key To Start", move=True, align="center", font=("Courier", 40, "bold"))
wn.exitonclick()
```